# Was Moon 44 shot at Ennis House or did they create a facsimile of it?

Tags: production, film-location, moon-44

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_44) and other sources claim that Roland Emmerich's [*Moon 44* (1990)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097910/) was shot in Germany (the [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_44) even adds that it was the last film he produced in his home area before moving to Hollywood). However, as a big Frank Lloyd Wright enthusiast I couldn't help but notice immediately in one of the first scenes (in the conference/briefing room) that it actually *looked* like it was shot in one of his textile block houses in Los Angeles (usually Ennis House), as many a film before it (like e.g. Deckard's appartment in *Blade Runner*). The concrete textile blocks are really unmistakable.

Is there any information **if these bits were actually shot in Los Angeles at Ennis House**? Despite the claims that the film was produced in Germany, I wouldn't discount this as a possibility, since the film already features a lot of US personell and those scenes are somewhat detached from the rest of the film anyway, so maybe it was a reshoot. However, does this mean Emmerich traveled to LA for that or were those scenes done by a second unit there? Or **did they genuinely recreate the look of Wright's masterpiece on the German set** for that scene (possibly as an hommage to the sci-fi classics that featured it before)? It's not like the film is particularly shy of "helping itself" to the works that came before it otherwise.

Comment: Ennis House is listed as a filming location on imdb.

Comment: Oh, really? I admittedly didn't check that (though, I haven't really found my way through the new IMDb interface yet anyway, couldn't even find the production country there).

Comment: Though, now IMDb's word kind of stands against Wikipedia's and even if the former is right, it's interesting why they filmed that at the other end of the world (and if Emmerich did that himself, maybe even while he was moving to Hollywood).

Answer (score 1):

Ennis House was definitely used as a location shoot for the film *Moon 44* (1990), according to film historian and artist Emanuel Röhss. It's mentioned several times in his seminal work on the use of the Ennis House in Hollywood films; *[Location Scout](https://www.lespressesdureel.com/EN/ouvrage.php?id=4571&menu=4)*.

[This panel](http://thomasduncangallery.com/files/ennishouse-timeline-legend.pdf) (below) from the [Thomas Duncan Gallery](https://thomasduncangallery.com/) archive shows the results of his research and highlights the wide array of shows and films that have used Ennis House as a futuristic or fantastical location.

[image]